# SQL - Use Value until End, then Use last value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have written a query that gives me Growth of an Estimate from 2015 - 2016.

I am using a Variable Called EBIT, EBIT with Date_Year = 2015 has data for Date_Month 2013-12-31 to 2016-12-31 while EBIT With Date_Year = 2016 has data for Date_Month 2013-12-31 to 2017-06-30.

Is there a way to do the exakt same as I've done but after 2016-12-31 use the last value of EBIT (2015) instead and hence keep going?

In the Code below EBIT (2015) & EBIT (2016) is just to illustrate the numbers.
The table furthest down is the optimal table that I am trying to get but I can't understand how I can get there ...

As you can see the Current Output stops at 2016-12-31 while the Desired Output assumes that EBIT (2015) = 936808 after it has no more values and EBIT (2016) keeps going until data for it ends.

I am thinking of maybe incorporating something like the code below yet I can't have a Max function inside of a Sum(Case when) and I also think this might not pick the maximum n2.EBIT for the max(Date_Month_Id) with same Date_Year_ID etc.

```
(
    SUM(case when n2.Date_Month_Id < (Select Max(Date_Month_Id) From EBIT where Date_Year_ID in (2015)) 
            Then n2.EBIT else max(n2.EBIT) end
    ) 
    /
    SUM(n1.EBIT) - 1) AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    SUM(n2.EBIT) As 'EBIT (2015)',
    SUM(n1.EBIT) AS 'EBIT (2016)',
    SUM(n2.EBIT) /
    SUM(n1.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
INNER JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month
WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and y1.date_year = 2015 AND y2.date_year = 2016 
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

Current Output:

```
date_Month  EBIT (2015) EBIT (2016) EBIT Growth 2015-2016
2013-12-31  2198051.670 2053514.548 0.070385
2014-01-31  1112047.668 1045523.283 0.063627
2014-02-28  1109221.007 1043085.024 0.063404
2014-03-31  1118112.429 1047602.842 0.067305
2014-04-30  1117082.270 1044455.198 0.069535
2014-05-31  1122019.824 1045228.639 0.073468
2014-06-30  1130536.274 1053516.159 0.073107
2014-07-31  1135838.665 1055882.605 0.075724
2014-08-31  1138886.938 1056331.236 0.078153
2014-09-30  1147685.937 1064254.322 0.078394
2014-10-31  1126437.959 1040798.042 0.082282
2014-11-30  1116292.468 1029127.634 0.084697
2014-12-31  1111509.880 1020233.204 0.089466
2015-01-31  1109692.378 1011895.933 0.096646
2015-02-28  1103494.875 1000990.365 0.102403
2015-03-31  1099507.246 996252.094  0.103643
2015-04-30  1094694.816 997653.412  0.097269
2015-05-31  1103352.777 1007836.533 0.094773
2015-06-30  1098103.559 1004344.223 0.093353
2015-07-31  1081689.371 994391.939  0.087789
2015-08-31  1064033.692 979809.245  0.085960
2015-09-30  1041604.341 971746.514  0.071888
2015-10-31  1044583.652 979410.989  0.066542
2015-11-30  1049158.666 989746.574  0.060027
2015-12-31  1022646.632 969556.360  0.054757
2016-01-31  990592.876  968797.454  0.022497
2016-02-29  961009.086  934777.852  0.028061
2016-03-31  942917.628  933858.404  0.009700
2016-04-30  937784.980  931500.111  0.006747
2016-05-31  941049.211  928974.727  0.012997
2016-06-30  930969.603  929102.681  0.002009
2016-07-31  926670.277  928979.675  -0.002486
2016-08-31  927442.570  929233.754  -0.001928
2016-09-30  924658.701  930248.793  -0.006010
2016-10-31  925569.857  930250.547  -0.005032
2016-11-30  938894.794  930156.559  0.009394
2016-12-31  936808.419  929592.092  0.007762
```

Desired Output (and the % Increase but I know how to implement that code):

```
date_month  EBIT(2015)  EBIT(2016)
31/12/2013  2198052 2053515
31/01/2014  1112048 1045523
28/02/2014  1109221 1043085
31/03/2014  1118112 1047603
30/04/2014  1117082 1044455
31/05/2014  1122020 1045229
30/06/2014  1130536 1053516
31/07/2014  1135839 1055883
31/08/2014  1138887 1056331
30/09/2014  1147686 1064254
31/10/2014  1126438 1040798
30/11/2014  1116292 1029128
31/12/2014  1111510 1020233
31/01/2015  1109692 1011896
28/02/2015  1103495 1000990
31/03/2015  1099507 996252
30/04/2015  1094695 997653
31/05/2015  1103353 1007837
30/06/2015  1098104 1004344
31/07/2015  1081689 994392
31/08/2015  1064034 979809
30/09/2015  1041604 971747
31/10/2015  1044584 979411
30/11/2015  1049159 989747
31/12/2015  1022647 969556
31/01/2016  990593  968797
29/02/2016  961009  934778
31/03/2016  942918  933858
30/04/2016  937785  931500
31/05/2016  941049  928975
30/06/2016  930970  929103
31/07/2016  926670  928980
31/08/2016  927443  929234
30/09/2016  924659  930249
31/10/2016  925570  930251
30/11/2016  938895  930157
31/12/2016  936808  929592
31/01/2017  936808  942461
28/02/2017  936808  936845
31/03/2017  936808  940401
30/04/2017  936808  933644
31/05/2017  936808  942218
```

Ps. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

---- EDIT ---------

Thanks to assistance I've been able to get the code below that yields almost exactly what I need. however if I keep the "AND y1.date_year = y2.date_Year + 1 condition I don't get values for n2.EBIT past 2017-01-31. If I remove it the query sums up way to many values for some reason ...
... do you know any work around?

Reworked Code:

```
 SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
     isnull(sum(case when y2.date_year = 2015 then n2.EBIT end),Max(innern2.december_value)) as 'EBIT 2015', 
    sum(case when y1.date_year = 2016 then n1.EBIT end) AS 'EBIT (2016)',
   sum(case when y1.date_year = 2016 then n1.EBIT end) / 
   isnull(sum(case when y2.date_year = 2015 then n2.EBIT end),SUM(innern2.december_value)) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month

LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT maxn2.date_year_id, SUM(maxn2.EBIT) as december_value
    FROM EBIT maxn2
    Inner join Date_Month As M on M.Date_Month_Id = maxn2.Date_Month_Id
    inner join Date_Year as Y on Y.Date_Year_Id = maxn2.Date_Year_Id
    WHERE Month(Date_Month) = 12  and year(Date_Month) = 2016
    GROUP BY maxn2.date_year_id
    ) as innern2 on innern2.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id - 1

WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 AND y1.date_year = y2.date_year + 1 
and n2.Date_Month_Id >= (Select Min(E.Date_Month_Id) from EBIT as E inner join Date_Year as Y on Y.Date_Year_Id = E.Date_Year_Id Where Y.Date_Year = 2016) 
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month asc;
```

OutPut with Constraint mentioned:

```
date_Month  EBIT 2015   EBIT (2016)
2013-12-31  2053514.548 2198051.670
2014-01-31  1045523.283 1112047.668
2014-02-28  1043085.024 1109221.007
2014-03-31  1047602.842 1118112.429
2014-04-30  1044455.198 1117082.270
2014-05-31  1045228.639 1122019.824
2014-06-30  1053516.159 1130536.274
2014-07-31  1055882.605 1135838.665
2014-08-31  1056331.236 1138886.938
2014-09-30  1064254.322 1147685.937
2014-10-31  1040798.042 1126437.959
2014-11-30  1029127.634 1116292.468
2014-12-31  1020233.204 1111509.880
2015-01-31  1011895.933 1109692.378
2015-02-28  1000990.365 1103494.875
2015-03-31  996252.094  1099507.246
2015-04-30  997653.412  1094694.816
2015-05-31  1007836.533 1103352.777
2015-06-30  1004344.223 1098103.559
2015-07-31  994391.939  1081689.371
2015-08-31  979809.245  1064033.692
2015-09-30  971746.514  1041604.341
2015-10-31  979410.989  1044583.652
2015-11-30  989746.574  1049158.666
2015-12-31  969556.360  1022646.632
2016-01-31  968797.454  990592.876
2016-02-29  934777.852  961009.086
2016-03-31  933858.404  942917.628
2016-04-30  931500.111  937784.980
2016-05-31  928974.727  941049.211
2016-06-30  929102.681  930969.603
2016-07-31  928979.675  926670.277
2016-08-31  929233.754  927442.570
2016-09-30  930248.793  924658.701
2016-10-31  930250.547  925569.857
2016-11-30  930156.559  938894.794
2016-12-31  929592.092  936808.419
2017-01-31  942617.388  NULL
2017-02-28  942617.388  NULL
2017-03-31  942617.388  NULL
2017-04-30  942617.388  NULL
2017-05-31  942617.388  NULL
```

Output with suggested constraint "AND y1.date_Year = 2016":

```
date_Month  EBIT 2015   EBIT (2016)
2013-12-31  2053514.548 8781104.520
2014-01-31  1045523.283 3330912.804
2014-02-28  1043085.024 3322433.491
2014-03-31  1047602.842 3349059.127
2014-04-30  1044455.198 3346078.340
2014-05-31  1045228.639 3360889.672
2014-06-30  1053516.159 3385242.192
2014-07-31  1055882.605 3401244.625
2014-08-31  1056331.236 3410616.294
2014-09-30  1064254.322 3436856.111
2014-10-31  1040798.042 3373162.267
2014-11-30  1029127.634 3342757.174
2014-12-31  1020233.204 4363552.086
2015-01-31  1011895.933 4384691.285
2015-02-28  1000990.365 4376807.747
2015-03-31  996252.094  4375725.598
2015-04-30  997653.412  4357711.561
2015-05-31  1007836.533 4392712.780
2015-06-30  1004344.223 4373955.988
2015-07-31  994391.939  4314820.563
2015-08-31  979809.245  4247412.535
2015-09-30  971746.514  4151358.468
2015-10-31  979410.989  4161422.299
2015-11-30  989746.574  4179141.525
2015-12-31  969556.360  4077629.132
2016-01-31  968797.454  2970088.034
2016-02-29  934777.852  2881375.640
2016-03-31  933858.404  2827941.356
2016-04-30  931500.111  2815130.846
2016-05-31  928974.727  2824951.723
2016-06-30  929102.681  2794527.987
2016-07-31  928979.675  2783688.491
2016-08-31  929233.754  2785958.962
2016-09-30  930248.793  2783949.407
2016-10-31  930250.547  2787387.285
2016-11-30  930156.559  2827684.912
2016-12-31  929592.092  2822043.195
2017-01-31  930177.105  1884922.522
2017-02-28  930177.105  1873690.578
2017-03-31  930177.105  1880802.312
2017-04-30  930177.105  1867287.280
2017-05-31  930177.105  1884436.230
```

Output without "and y1.date_year = y2.date_year - 1 constraint:

```
date_Month  EBIT 2015   EBIT (2016)
2013-12-31  4255200.364 8781104.520
2014-01-31  3237430.013 3330912.804
2014-02-28  3201517.162 3322433.491
2014-03-31  3190328.126 3349059.127
2014-04-30  3176902.028 3346078.340
2014-05-31  3171643.267 3360889.672
2014-06-30  3172452.363 3385242.192
2014-07-31  3169541.043 3401244.625
2014-08-31  3170477.020 3410616.294
2014-09-30  3192395.112 3436856.111
2014-10-31  3120825.630 3373162.267
2014-11-30  3082544.372 3342757.174
2014-12-31  4002614.551 4363552.086
2015-01-31  3997360.080 4384691.285
2015-02-28  3968359.858 4376807.747
2015-03-31  3965754.869 4375725.598
2015-04-30  3971742.802 4357711.561
2015-05-31  4010919.518 4392712.780
2015-06-30  3997415.185 4373955.988
2015-07-31  3966592.901 4314820.563
2015-08-31  3911382.409 4247412.535
2015-09-30  3871093.275 4151358.468
2015-10-31  3900314.386 4161422.299
2015-11-30  3938511.747 4179141.525
2015-12-31  3862780.776 4077629.132
2016-01-31  2903039.552 2970088.034
2016-02-29  2801085.898 2881375.640
2016-03-31  2798222.402 2827941.356
2016-04-30  2794500.333 2815130.846
2016-05-31  2787967.181 2824951.723
2016-06-30  2788351.043 2794527.987
2016-07-31  2787982.025 2783688.491
2016-08-31  2788744.262 2785958.962
2016-09-30  2790746.379 2783949.407
2016-10-31  2790751.641 2787387.285
2016-11-30  2790469.677 2827684.912
2016-12-31  2789361.289 2822043.195
2017-01-31  942617.388  1884922.522
2017-02-28  942617.388  1873690.578
2017-03-31  942617.388  1880802.312
2017-04-30  942617.388  1867287.280
2017-05-31  942617.388  1884436.230
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a left join?

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    isnull(SUM(n2.EBIT),936808)  As 'EBIT (2015)',
    SUM(n1.EBIT) AS 'EBIT (2016)',
    isnull(SUM(n2.EBIT),936808) /
    SUM(n1.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month
WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and y1.date_year = 2015 AND y2.date_year = 2016 
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

Also, comparing you output column names, I was thinking your where clause may have mixed the years, so should be:

```
WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and y1.date_year = 2016 AND y2.date_year = 2015
```

EDIT---------

Add in a inline table to get the december EBIT from previous year

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    isnull(SUM(n2.EBIT),MAX(innern2.december_value))  As 'EBIT (2015)',
    SUM(n1.EBIT) AS 'EBIT (2016)',
    isnull(SUM(n2.EBIT),MAX(innern2.december_value)) /
    SUM(n1.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id
    AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month
    AND year(y1.date_year) = year(y2.date_year) - 1

LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT year(Y.date_year) as [year], SUM(maxn2.EBIT) as december_value
    FROM EBIT maxn2
    Inner join Date_Month As M on M.Date_Month_Id = maxn2.Date_Month_Id
    inner join Date_Year as Y on Y.Date_Year_Id = maxn2.Date_Year_Id
    WHERE Month(M.Date_Month) = 12
    GROUP BY year(Y.date_year)
    ) as innern2 on innern2.[year] = year(y1.date_year) - 1

WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and year(y1.date_year) >= 2016
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

To check this approach, if you run this part from the inner query, you should get a list of years and the value of the december EBIT for that year:

```
SELECT year(Y.date_year) as [year], SUM(maxn2.EBIT) as december_value
FROM EBIT maxn2
Inner join Date_Month As M on M.Date_Month_Id = maxn2.Date_Month_Id
inner join Date_Year as Y on Y.Date_Year_Id = maxn2.Date_Year_Id
WHERE Month(M.Date_Month) = 12
GROUP BY year(Y.date_year)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeeed I had mixed up y1 and y2...

I tried a left join previously but since my WHERE clause removes all that values in which y2.date_year <> 2015 the Null values do not show up anyway. I think this code could work if 
1) I can ammend the where caluse somehow to look where y2.date_year = 2015 until we are at end and then allow for the last value.
and 2) if I could rewrite the code to allow the 936808 number to be dynamic (the last value for a given y2.date_year) instead of constant.
Any more tips?

Comment: @CedricVongheer OK - consider joining as an inline table query. See edit to answer. Sorry it will need some interpretation from yourself, but I am assuming a bit as to the exact data structure your tables have.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, please see ---EDIT-- in my original post.

tl:dr -> 
Error says that I need to group or aggregate innern2.december_value so to get any output I've put sum(innern2.deceber_value) but this value is ofc. to high. Problem 2 is that I don't get the values from EBIT (2016), probably due to the where caluse because if I remove the constraints I do get values but everything get distorted.

Comment: @CedricVongheer Ah yes, Instead of `SUM(innern2.december_value)` use aggregate function min or max (should equal the same value): `MAX(innern2.december_value)`

Comment: @CedricVongheer, also instead of hardcoding the 2016 into the inner query, a nicer way would be to configure like this as my edited answer above.

Comment: @CedricVongheer I keep missing bits. Specifiy you only want 2015 onwards like this: `WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and year(y1.date_year) >= 2016` and append this to the join of n2 `AND year(y1.date_year) = year(y2.date_year) - 1` - see amendements in answer

Comment: not really, I'm sorry. This data is a bit hard to understand but it is Estimates taken at different intervalls (2 years prior and 1 year post). Hence We here have EBIT estimates 2012-12-31 to 2016-12-31 for the year 2015, and we have EBIT estimates 2013-12-31 to 2017-06-30 for the year 2016. My ultimate goal is to start from 2013-12-31 (when both have values) and go to 2016-12-31 through using actual values, then keep going to 2017-06-30 by using actual values for 2016 yet last value for 2015.

Comment: The problem with approach above is that it does not hinder y2.date_year which means that the sum becomes way to large. When I add a AND y2.date_year = 2015 I get the right sums but ofcourse I don't get the list to go past 2016-12-31 (because that is the actual end of n2.EBIT through the constraint). I think a sum(case when) with the help of your inner table might work somehow.